# extract an attribute of a specific type from JSON API

Tags: ios, json, json-api

How do I extract the attributes of a specific type from a JSON API format string? I used `NSJSONSerialization`- but that extracts the attributes and puts it under included.attributes

```
..."included":[{"id":"","type":"name1","attributes":{...}},{"id":"","type":"form-data","attributes":{..}}]}
```

that serializes into:

```
included =     (
            {
        attributes =             {..};id = "";
        type = "name1";
    },
            {
        attributes =             {...};
        id = "";
        type = "name2";
    }
);
}
```

is there a way to extract values of attribute based on value of type?

Comment: that will PHP developer have to manage that.

Comment: :-) json API format- they refuse to change anything.

Comment: they have to do that , thats their responsibly. otherwise you have to set dictionary or use NSPredicate Function and Sort them as per your need.

Comment: alright. i will close this then. my code did solve my problem. even if not in the way that i wanted :-) thank you.

Comment: ok great. keep coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used the following code to extract what i needed:

```
    for (NSMutableArray* oneRow in attributes) {
    if([[oneRow valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"name"]){
        formAttribute = [oneRow valueForKey:@"attributes"];
    }
}
```

i had hoped to find a method or predefined function that could do this-if there is, hope you add it as an answer.